# HTML form PHP post not hitting

Tags: php, html

Not sure why I am having this issue, I am making a edit form that will allow the users to update data.

I have an HTML form that looks like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="updatefacility.php">
    <label for="fac_number">Facility Number: </label>
    <input type="text" id="fac_number" name="fac_number" value="<?php if (!empty($facNum)) echo $facNum; ?>" /><br />
    <label for="fac_name">Facility Name: </label>
    <input type="text" id="fac_name" name="fac_name" value="<?php if (!empty($facName)) echo $facName; ?>" /><br />
    <label for="fac_address">Address: </label>
    <input type="text" id="fac_address" name="fac_address" value="<?php if (!empty($facAddress)) echo $facAddress; ?>" /><br />
    <input type="button" value="Update" name="update">
</form>
```

When I click my button I should be hitting `updatefacility.php` which looks like this:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);        
if (!$dbc) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

 if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

     echo "test";
 }
```

When I am clicking my button I am expecting my form to submit and return a blank page with the word "test" on it, however nothing happens..

Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: `type="button"` doesn't work with POST arrays.

Comment: Booom - forms done right FTW.

Comment: HA downvoted - SO trolls too strong

Comment: Not my downvote but it's probably because people thought you didn't research it and has been asked often.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah that's ok. It was my own mistake for not paying closer attention to what I am doing, silly mistake - it's been a long day.

Comment: Nobody's perfect; I get long days too. After staring at a computer screen for so long, makes us all run for the nearest bistro for a double shot of Espresso ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh baby, I wish I could run for one right now!

Comment: At this time of day, I'll settle for a cappuccino, *per favore*. latte solamente, non bisogno di zucchero, *grazie* ;-)

Comment: @JayBlanchard is that sarcasm? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: It was a bit of silliness based on a comment you made on another post @BigRabbit

Comment: @JayBlanchard oh yeah I knew that, but in all seriousness is there anything wrong with the way I am doing this form? - other than what the question is asking.

Comment: Not that I can see once you implement the fix @BigRabbit

Comment: @JayBlanchard K thanks, just wanted to ensure I haven't done anything incorrectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the input type from button to submit.

Like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Update" name="update">
```

Comment: You should try hard not LOL :D

Comment: No problem im glad i could help. If you are satisfied with the answer you can check it as the right answer so that anybody can see that the question was already answered :-)